# Comparing timestamps in WP_Query

Tags: wordpress, timestamp

I can't figure out how to compare timestamps in the WP_query. On the site, classes/events are entered as posts with meta added for the date they begin. In `calendar_functions.php`, `$begtime` is defined as the timestamp for the date the class/event starts (not the date the post is created) and $today is defined as today's timestamp. I've tested both of those and they do return correct values.

The below code works fine, it displays a random class/event... except that past classes/events show up. I want to be able to only display items that happen from today on. Its not an option to go in and delete classes/events that have already happened.
Not sure how to handle the `>=` part.

```
<?php include('calendar_functions.php'); ?>
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('"$begtime >= $today"&posts_per_page=1&cat=5,43&orderby=rand');
if (have_posts()) : while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
$do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;
?>
```

I will also need to be able to compare two sets of dates, as some classes have two sessions, ex. `$begtime >= $today -or- $begtime2 >= $today`. (`$begtime2` is also already defined).

Answer (score 0):

you need something like this.

```
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
    // posts  30 to 60 days old
    $where .= " AND post_date >= '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-60 days')) . "'" . " AND post_date <= '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')) . "'";
    return $where;
}

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
$query = new WP_Query( $query_string );
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Time_Parameters

Comment: The problem with that is its not the post date that I need to use, but rather a date that is entered in a meta field. Plus it needs to also have 'posts_per_page=1&cat=5,43&orderby=rand' in the query as well.